# Redirecting to binary image file after creating on the fly image resizing

Tags: php, image, redirect, resize

i have an image re sizing script in php which returns the image path after been resized when passed the image path,height and width parameters. My problem is i dont want url of the image but to actually redirect to that particular image path ending in .jpg or png whatever is applicable.

Resizing function is here.

```
<?php
function resize($imagePath,$opts=null){

    # start configuration

    $cacheFolder = './cache/'; # path to your cache folder, must be writeable by web server
    $remoteFolder = $cacheFolder.'remote/'; # path to the folder you wish to download remote images into
    $quality = 90; # image quality to use for ImageMagick (0 - 100)

    $cache_http_minutes = 20;   # cache downloaded http images 20 minutes

    $path_to_convert = 'convert'; # this could be something like /usr/bin/convert or /opt/local/share/bin/convert

    ## you shouldn't need to configure anything else beyond this point

    $purl = parse_url($imagePath);
    $finfo = pathinfo($imagePath);
    $ext = $finfo['extension'];

    # check for remote image..
    if(isset($purl['scheme']) && $purl['scheme'] == 'http'):
        # grab the image, and cache it so we have something to work with..
        list($filename) = explode('?',$finfo['basename']);
        $local_filepath = $remoteFolder.$filename;
        $download_image = true;
        if(file_exists($local_filepath)):
            if(filemtime($local_filepath) < strtotime('+'.$cache_http_minutes.' minutes')):
                $download_image = false;
            endif;
        endif;
        if($download_image == true):
            $img = file_get_contents($imagePath);
            file_put_contents($local_filepath,$img);
        endif;
        $imagePath = $local_filepath;
    endif;

    if(file_exists($imagePath) == false):
        $imagePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$imagePath;
        if(file_exists($imagePath) == false):
            return 'image not found';
        endif;
    endif;

    if(isset($opts['w'])): $w = $opts['w']; endif;
    if(isset($opts['h'])): $h = $opts['h']; endif;

    $filename = md5_file($imagePath);

    if(!empty($w) and !empty($h)):
        $newPath = $cacheFolder.$filename.'_w'.$w.'_h'.$h.(isset($opts['crop']) && $opts['crop'] == true ? "_cp" : "").(isset($opts['scale']) && $opts['scale'] == true ? "_sc" : "").'.'.$ext;
    elseif(!empty($w)):
        $newPath = $cacheFolder.$filename.'_w'.$w.'.'.$ext; 
    elseif(!empty($h)):
        $newPath = $cacheFolder.$filename.'_h'.$h.'.'.$ext;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;

    $create = true;

    if(file_exists($newPath) == true):
        $create = false;
        $origFileTime = date("YmdHis",filemtime($imagePath));
        $newFileTime = date("YmdHis",filemtime($newPath));
        if($newFileTime < $origFileTime):
            $create = true;
        endif;
    endif;

    if($create == true):
        if(!empty($w) and !empty($h)):

            list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imagePath);
            $resize = $w;

            if($width > $height):
                $resize = $w;
                if(isset($opts['crop']) && $opts['crop'] == true):
                    $resize = "x".$h;               
                endif;
            else:
                $resize = "x".$h;
                if(isset($opts['crop']) && $opts['crop'] == true):
                    $resize = $w;
                endif;
            endif;

            if(isset($opts['scale']) && $opts['scale'] == true):
                $cmd = $path_to_convert." ".$imagePath." -resize ".$resize." -quality ".$quality." ".$newPath;
            else:
                $cmd = $path_to_convert." ".$imagePath." -resize ".$resize." -size ".$w."x".$h." xc:".(isset($opts['canvas-color'])?$opts['canvas-color']:"transparent")." +swap -gravity center -composite -quality ".$quality." ".$newPath;
            endif;

        else:
            $cmd = $path_to_convert." ".$imagePath." -thumbnail ".(!empty($h) ? 'x':'').$w."".(isset($opts['maxOnly']) && $opts['maxOnly'] == true ? "\>" : "")." -quality ".$quality." ".$newPath;
        endif;

        $c = exec($cmd);

    endif;

    # return cache file path
    return str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$newPath);

}

?>
```

$newpath returns the actual path of an image but i want to redirect to the returned image path i.e http://localhost/myfolder/image.jpg .so if i pass a parameter it should redirect me to the binary file image path.So far i have tried using header("Location: echo $newpath"); but its showing $newPath on the url. Help!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be `header("Location: $newpath")`.  If that doesn't work, try `header('Location: '.$newpath);`.

[Look here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more information.